# Service container and Factories simultaneously

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

This is my first post so if I doing something wrong please correct me :)

I'm reading a lot of posts (not only on stackoverflow) and I know that dependency injection is the right way to write the code. But I nowhere find info whether the use dependency injection container excludes use factory?

I'm beginning to write the code using dependency injection. Now I have a few features written with DI and I need a container to make code more clearly (application is in symfony 1.4 so I use external DI container http://container.thephpleague.com/).

Let me show some example. I have class `TvMonitor` which I use to check some conditions and notify me if some condition was not fulfilled (display info on special monitor). Now my code looks similar to this:

```
class TvMonitor
{
    public function check(){ /* run check on every injected checker */ }
    public function addChecker(CheckerInterface $checker){ ... }
    public function addCheckers(CheckerInterface[] $chekers) { /* make foreach and use `addChecker` */ }
}

interface CheckerInterface
{
    public function check();
    public function getDetails(): array;
}

class CheckerFactory
{
    public function getForFirstMonitor(): array
    {
        return [
            new FileError('/some/file/path'),
            new ApiBugs(new SomeApiClient('http://base_url/', 'api_key', new HttpClient()))
        ];
    }

    public function getForSecondMonitor(): array
    {
        return [
            new FileError('/some/other/file/path'),
            new OtherApiBugs(new SomeOtherApiClient())
        ];
    }
```

}

In controllers code looks that:

```
/* first monitor controller */
$checker_factory = new CheckerFactory();

$monitor = new TvMonitor();
$monitor->addCheckers($checker_factory->getForFirstMonitor());

$monitor->check();


/* second monitor controller */
$checker_factory = new CheckerFactory();

$monitor = new TvMonitor();
$monitor->addCheckers($checker_factory->getForSecondMonitor());

$monitor->check();
```

Now I have 2 ideas. One is to remove factory and keep in container 2 instances of TvMonitor with different checker list:

```
$container
    ->add('fisrt_checker', FileError::class)
    ->withArgument('/some/file/path');
$container
    ->add('second_checker', ApiBugs::class)
    ->withArgument(...);

$container
    ->add('third_checker', FileError::class)
    ->withArgument('/some/other/file/path')
$container
    ->add('fourth_checker', OtherApiBugs::class)
    ->withArgument(...)

$container
    ->add('first_tv_monitor', TvMonitor::class)
    ->withMethodCall('addCheckers', ['first_checker', 'second_checker']);

$container
    ->add('second_tv_monitor', TvMonitor::class)
    ->withMethodCall('addCheckers', ['first_checker', 'fourth_checker']);
```

Controllers will looks that:

```
/* first monitor controller */
$monitor = $container->get('first_tv_monitor');

$monitor->check();


/* second monitor controller */
$monitor = $container->get('second_tv_monitor');

$monitor->check();
```

Second idea is to make some changes in factory (inject inside all object needed to create checkers) and register it in container:

```
class CheckerFactory
{
    public function __contstruct(SomeApiClient $some_api_client, SomeOtherApiClient $some_other_api_client){ ... }
    /* rest method are the same but use injected objects */
}

$container
    ->add('some_api_client', SomeApiClient::class);
$container
    ->add('some_other_api_client', SomeOtherApiClient::class);

$container
    ->add('checker_factory', CheckerFactory::class)
    ->withArgument('some_api_client')
    ->withArgument('some_other_api_client');

$container
    ->add('tv_monitor', TvMonitor::class);
```

Controllers will looks that:

```
/* first monitor controller */
$checker_factory = $container->get('checker_factory');

$monitor = $container->get('tv_monitor');
$monitor->addCheckers($checker_factory->getForFirstMonitor());

$monitor->check();


/* second monitor controller */
$checker_factory = $container->get('checker_factory');

$monitor = $container->get('tv_monitor');
$monitor->addCheckers($checker_factory->getForSecondMonitor());

$monitor->check();
```

I think that first idea is not good because container (or rather its configuration) is doing too much.

I will prefered the second idea because every element doing one things:

- container keep single instances
- controller decide which package of checkers will use
- factory decide which checkers will be included in every package

Please let me know what you thin about this ideas (or maybe you have another). I hope that someone with more experience in DI will help me with this decision :)

Comment: Kind of hard to say.  Do you need to adjust checkers after getting a specific monitor?  If not then maybe a MonitorFactory::create($monitorNumber);  That hides all the messy checking stuff from your controller.

Comment: Checker I need only to inject them inside monitor. 
If I create MonitorFactory checker will be created inside it? I think it is not good to doing everything inside this Factory.